# Abstract Algebra Symmetric Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

$$
\begin{align}
\beta &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
1 & 3 & 8 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 2 & 4
\end{bmatrix} \\
&= (23847)(56) \\
&= (27)(24)(28)(23)(56)
\end{align}
$$
In writing this permutation as a product of transpositions, can anyone please explain why the 1 left is out?

Written in disjoint product notation the group would look like $(1)(23847)(56)$ right?

Comment: No! In cycle notation you don't write numbers on which the permutation does nothing. A cycle $(abc)$ mean that the permutation sends $a \mapsto b$, $b \mapsto c$, and $c \mapsto a$.

Comment: Also, please note that we prefer that questions are not asked in picture form. Some explicative pictures are fine, but a question should be understandable even without them. Please have a look at our [basic MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to write math on this forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $1$ is getting fixed so you can drop it. Any cycle of $1$ length i.e. (a) can be dropped , although you can write it too. It is just a way to make it look less complicated